# Streamflow plot not matching mgrid

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am plotting a streamplot of a 2D ODE system using the Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Y, X = np.mgrid[-4:4:100j, -4:4:100j]

U =  -0.5*X - Y
V =  X - Y
plt.streamplot(X, Y, U, V, density=[1, 1])
plt.show()
```

However I am getting the following plot where it is extending the x and y axis by an additional unit, 5 instead of 4 even though the mgrid is -4 to 4 in both directions. I've tried different ranges but without success. Any ideas on how to confine the plot to -4:-4 and -4:4

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
ax.set(xlim=(-4,4), ylim=(-4,4))
```

to manually set the limits:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
Y, X = np.mgrid[-4:4:100j, -4:4:100j]
U =  -0.5*X - Y
V =  X - Y
ax.streamplot(X, Y, U, V, density=[1, 1])
ax.set(xlim=(-4,4), ylim=(-4,4))
plt.show()
```

[image]